# Entity framework throws exception with Add-Migration Altering column datatype

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

When I change the SchoolclassNumber datatype **string** to **integer** and do Add-Migration "blubb" after and then Update-Database I get this exception:

```
public partial class Changed_Field_SchoolclassNumber_DataType_To_Integer : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.SchoolclassCode", "SchoolclassNumber", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.SchoolclassCode", "SchoolclassNumber", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 10));
    }
}


Applying explicit migration: 201507021940211_Changed_Field_SchoolclassNumber_DataType_To_Integer.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Das Objekt-Objekt 'DF__Schoolcla__Schoo__34C8D9D1' ist vom Spalte-Objekt 'SchoolclassNumber' abhängig.
Fehler bei ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN SchoolclassNumber, da mindestens ein Objekt auf diese Spalte zugreift.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
ClientConnectionId:e3983fcb-901f-47ac-ac74-cc5d97b27542
Error Number:5074,State:1,Class:16
Das Objekt-Objekt 'DF__Schoolcla__Schoo__34C8D9D1' ist vom Spalte-Objekt 'SchoolclassNumber' abhängig.
Fehler bei ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN SchoolclassNumber, da mindestens ein Objekt auf diese Spalte zugreift.
```

**QUESTION**

Why can I not update the database?

### UPDATE

This is my SchoolclassCode definition:

```
 public SchoolclassCodeConfiguration()
        {
            base.Property(p => p.SchoolclassNumber).IsRequired();
            base.Property(p => p.SubjectName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(10);
            base.Property(p => p.ClassIdentifier).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(2);
            base.HasMany(p => p.Pupils)
            .WithMany(p => p.SchoolclassCodes)
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapLeftKey("SchoolclassCodeId");
                x.MapRightKey("PupilId");
                x.ToTable("SchoolclassCodePupil");
            });
        }
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What was the migration when the `SchoolclassNumber` column was originally created? Did you add a `defaultValue` at that time?

Comment: No, I can not remember a defaultValue. It was defined as nullable automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the column you're trying to alter has some object attached (default value definition?) that needs to be removed before you can alter the column.

> The modified column cannot be any one of the following:
>
> ...
>
> - Associated with a default definition.

*https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273(v=sql.110).aspx*